# stopping HTML5 roulette wheel on a preselected item

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas, spinning

I've found this very interesting and useful article.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

In the tutorials above the wheel stops at a random item. Is there anyway to stop this wheel smoothly on a item that has already been selected on a random basis? Also it has to spin for some random times then it has to halt at a item that we want it to stop at.

Please anyone help me on this.